# Using accompaniment styles?

Tags: keyboard

Can you use the accompaniment styles on keyboards for your own composition if you don't have a backup band? Any singers or bands using rhythms machines, accompaniment styles in their songs?

Answer (score 2):

It would be perfectly normal to use the built in styles while songwriting, in place of a full band or production. It is unusual to use built-in keyboard styles in finished arrangements, but there are exceptions, such as John Shuttleworth:

Comment: All in chorus… Gordon is a moron… Gordon is a moron!! [If you don't get that, look up who plays John Shuttleworth [hint Graham Fellows] & the hit he had as Jilted John in the late 70s ;)